# Can't open file for input C++

Tags: c++

```
string iName, oName; //input and output file names, respectively
double avgIn;

cout << "Enter file name for input: ";
getline(cin, iName) || die("Could not read input file name");
if (iName.empty())
    iName = DEF_IN_NAME;

ifstream fin;
fin.open(iName);
if (!fin) die("Could not open " + iName + " for input\n");
```

In this section of my code, I take in a string for the name of the input file to be opened and if nothing is entered, I set it to DEF_IN_NAME (Which is "input.txt"). I have tried entering "i.txt" as well as entering nothing (defaulting to "input.txt") and in both cases my program calls the die function (simply outputs error message and exits program).

My files are in the same folder as my .exe file so I'm not sure why this is happening. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I should mention that the second call to die is performed, not the first. That is, the file cannot be opened for input.

I am running this on windows 10 from Visual Studio Express 2013 (debugging)

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your operating system (or perhaps Windows with .exe?), or how you start the program. The usual cause is that the systems "current directory" isn't the one you expect it to be.

Comment: I don't know about C++ but in C you'd print `strerror(errno)` to get the reason why the open failed.

Comment: @BoPersson apologies, added more information to original post.

Comment: "working directory" is not necessarily the same as where the EXE is (and when launching from inside Visual Studio, is not the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not specify the explicit path for the file to be read, the run time library will default to the process current working directory.  If you are running the program in the debugger, the current working directory will be your project directory rather than the location where the executable is linked.

Comment: Unless you change the project properties, "Debugging" tab.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein I have tried placing my files in both the project directory as well as the location where the executable is linked and get the same result either way.

Comment: @MV94 Write a file and see where it winds up.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you! This has resolved the issue for me. With this I located where the files are being read from/ written out to.